# Would it be a security risk if I moved PsTools to the windows system32 folder?

Tags: windows-10

Microsfot Sysinternals has a helper program called [PsTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) inside this PsTools suite are a bunch of .exe tools that I use regularly from a command line.
[image: Tools]

I was thinking about moving all these files to my system32 directory so they would be available on my prompt path. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Surely there's another way to put something in the execution path in Windows.

Comment: Right there is, but why clutter up my env variables

Comment: Why clutter up your system32?

Comment: Good point I guess. I was thinking that its already cluttered and filled with executables.

Comment: Even if it is, it's not the correct place for random executables, security issues aside. It's easier to maintain a system that doesn't deviate too far from the standard.

Comment: Not relevant to where they are stored, but having them at all will give an attacker some juicy built in tools to leverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use them from \Windows\ for easy quick deployment.

No problem whatsoever from a security perspective.

I try not to use the system directories, as things are hard to trace in there already, but directly in \Windows\ things are very clear and easy to follow from a "what exe files should be there" perspective.